Mutating an ES6 Map while iterating with forEach
In my ES6 <String,Boolean> Map, I need to change all keys that end with :1 to false in a button-click function.
I'm using the forEach(v,k) Map method. For some reason it includes the Value as the 1st param and the Key as the 2nd param (I would have thought  it would be the opposite), and also I only need to scan the keys, not the values.
My concern is, is it safe to mutate the map while iterating this way? In this case I'm not adding new keys, I'm just mutating the value. If I did add new entries, would the forEach pick it up or still iterate the old entries?
 const handleBackButton = () => {
    errorMap.forEach((value:boolean, key:string) => {
        if (key.endsWith(":1")) {
            errorMap.set(key, false);
        }
    });


Yes, the callback from Map.prototype.forEachis (value, key, map). Another way is to use for (const [key,value] of errorMap) {/* code */}

Related: ES6: Is it dangerous to delete elements from Set/Map during iteration?


is it safe to mutate the map while iterating this way?

Yes, maps preserve the insertion order, so even if a value is mutated, the iteration will not be altered:


const map = new Map()
  .set(1, "a")
  .set(2, "b");
  
map.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key, value)); 
/* 
logs:
1 a 
2 b
*/

//update the first key
map.set(1, "z");

map.forEach((value, key) => console.log(key, value));
/* 
logs:
1 z
2 b
*/




If I did add new entries, would the forEach pick it up or still iterate the old entries?

Yes, Map#forEach() iterates over the live map as it updates.


const map = new Map()
  .set(1, "a")
  .set(2, "b");
  
map.forEach((value, key) => {
  if (key === 1) // add one more entry once
    map.set(3, "c");

  console.log(key, value);
});



